# How to get RSS feed link in Joomla 2.5?

Tags: rss, joomla2.5

I need to get RSS XML of a category in Joomla! 2.5. I appended "&format=feed&type=rss" at the end of the category url in previous version of Joomla and it show me the XML in the FF window.

In 2.5 it forces me to download an index.php file and the XML codes are inside it. But I need to get XML directly not via index.php file because I have a some codes to parse the XML.

Is there any different way to get it in 2.5 directly ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Syndication Feeds module to set-up RSS feeds in Joomla.

I'm not sure why it's forcing a download of the index.php file. Perhaps this is a permissions use for the files? Or the server isn't configured properly for MIME types because it shouldn't download the index.php file.